# Stepping through c code in emacs

Tags: c++, c, gdb

I am trying to step through code in emacs and am looking for a plugin which will displa the contents of an element when I hover over it. Is there any plugin like this currently? How do you step through code with emacs?

Comment: See the `gdb`-tag you added. `M-x gdb` is one tool for debugging C/C++. There is also the [realgud](https://github.com/realgud/realgud/wiki/Features) project.

Comment: You can also do `M-x gdb-many-windows`(after doing `M-x gdb`) to see things like locals, threads, breakpoints, etc. There is also great toolbar to do various jumps in a debugger.

Comment: There's also `gud-gdb`, which provides a nice interface for GDB that nicely integrates with GNU Emacs.